# Отдельный поток

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

```
procedure hash;
begin
Form3.Show; CloseHandle(tr);
end;

procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
tr:=beginthread(nil,0,addr(hash),nil,0,id);
end;
```

Когда создается форма, она пустая ничего нет, в основной форме есть такая строчка: `Form3:=TForm3.Create(Self);` т.е. форма как бы есть и если вызвать `Show` не через поток а просто например через кнопку то все нормально, в чем проблема? почему форма через поток создается не так?
Ошибка: EOSError 1400 "Недопустимый дескриптор окна"

Comment: потому что нельзя так делать. Нельзя создавать формы не в основном потоке.

Comment: *Через поток даете сигнал к основному процессу* что нужно создать форму, например через `post_message`, в дочерней потоке не сможете создать форму родительского процесса, как `сказали выше`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попытайся через Synhronize или создать форму в потоке. 
И ты уверен что проблема в Form3.Show; а не CloseHandle(tr);? (раздели на два рядка что б дебагере было видно)

(завтра дополню ответ)

И как так поток создаешь? Чем TThread не угодил?

**Дополнение**

Этот код у меня работает:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Hide;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure begin Form2.Show end).Start;
end;
```

но всё же лучше так:

```
type
   TMyThread = class (TThread)
   private
     procedure ShowForm2;
   protected
     procedure Execute; override;
   end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.Hide;
  with TMyThread.Create(True) do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Start;
  end;
end;

{ TMyThread }

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Synchronize(ShowForm2);
end;

procedure TMyThread.ShowForm2;
begin
  Form2.Show;
end;
```